# in android studio 4.0 unknown facet type : python

Tags: python, plugins, android-studio-4.0

I have an error after updating to android studio 4.0.

Error Loading Project: Cannot load 2 facets Details...
[image]

I have already installed Python Community Edition(193.6911.25) and enabled it.

But nothing changed.

What can I do?
Please help.